# How to split large spark dataframe(5m rows)/csv file into chunk with same header for each dataframe(Optimized solution)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pyspark, dask

I have large csv file(5GB) which contains the ~50M rows. I want to make the smaller chunk csv(~1M rows) from original csv file. I tried below approaches to chunk but takes lots of time to perform the chunk:-

```
1. I used Pandas to read data from csv and make chunk and write into chunk csv file.

import pandas
rows = pd.read_csv('test.csv', chunksize=1000000)
for i, chunck in enumerate(rows):
     chunck.to_csv('/out{}_{}.csv'.format(i, 'test'))
For this execution it takes around 3 mins.

2. I used DASK to perform the same operation

import dask.dataframe
data = dask.dataframe.read_csv('test.csv')
data.to_csv('/test-*.csv')
For this it takes the same time 3 mins
```

SO, I tried to use spark dataframe to reduce the execution time. I am able to read csv successfully from pyspark but not able to make chunks(dataframes) with the same header for each chunk so, I can write the each chunk into individual csv file.

Could you help me how to make smallest chunks with same header and write into csv using pyspark?

Comment: Did you try `df.coalesce(50).write.csv('mycsv.csv')`?

Comment: No but it can't work for my case because, I have to make small chunks data like(1000-2000 rows, 2000-3000 rows).

Comment: But the more partitions you set using coalesce, the more smaller output files you will have.

Comment: Yes, it work as expected, the file names get created with default names, How do I add custom file name.

Comment: I don't think you can directly in Spark, but you can always do it in Python :) Would you be so kind to upvote and accept my solution?

Answer (score 4):

For SPARK try:

```
df.coalesce(50).write.csv('mycsv.csv')
```

The more partitions you set using coalesce, the more smaller output files you will have. It's better than `repartition`, because it's not shuffling the data.

Then to rename files in folder mycsv.csv:

```
import os
path = 'test.csv'
files = os.listdir(path)
print(files)

for index, file in enumerate(files):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, f'ip_{index:03d}.csv'))
```

You can define your own file format in `f'ip_{index:03d}.csv` part :)

Comment: Thanks for this but I want to custom file name like with timestamp or input file name for e.g ip_1.csv, ip_2.csv etc

Comment: It's not possible to change the "part" prefix  when using standard spark write methods. You can implement your own FileOutputFormat or just simply change all files name in Python.